# How to change agenda buffer font size?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Each time I load the agenda buffer, I have to do `C-x C-+++` for the content to be a readable size.

How could I modify init so I don't have to do `C-x C-+++` anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a call to `text-scale-adjust` with the appropriate increment to your `org-agenda-finalize-hook`:

```el
(add-hook 'org-agenda-finalize-hook (lambda () (text-scale-adjust 3)))
```

But "solutions" like this are at best band-aids for bad configuration IMO. You should investigate *why* the agenda is appearing too small.

As a start, what does the agenda look like if you start with `emacs -q`? If that looks OK, then you'll have to go through your init file and figure out what is happening. `C-u C-x =` in various places in the agenda will give you information about fonts and faces, so you can narrow your investigation a bit. Find out what you are doing in your init file with these fonts and faces, understand what is going wrong and fix it.

If `emacs -q` gives you problems as well, then try with `emacs -Q`: if that shows no problems, chances are that your distro is shipping a config file that causes problems. IIRC, Debian was shipping such a distro-specific config file and was causing problems, although I don't think the problems they caused had anything to do with unreadably small agendas.

---

EDIT: `org-agenda-finalize-hook` is run after the initial agenda is created, but it also runs when the agenda is redone with `g`. In the latter case, we don't want to do the size adjustment, so modify the function that the hook runs to check whether the size is different from the default:

```el
(defun my/org-agenda-adjust-text-size ()
  (if (= text-scale-mode-amount 0)
      (text-scale-adjust 3)))

(add-hook 'org-agenda-finalize-hook #'my/org-agenda-adjust-text-size)
```

I defined a named function to add to the hook, both because the function is a bit more complicated now, but also because it is "best practice": it makes it easier to delete it from the hook with

```el
(remove-hook 'org-agenda-finalize-hook #'my/org-agenda-adjust-text-size)
```

Comment: Hi NickD, thanks for the solution and the explanations, Your solution works, it brings Agenda buffer fonts to the same size as my `.org` buffers.  `emacs -q` and `emacs -Q` give the same result: font size is too small (same size as Agenda buffer before applying your solution) in every buffer (`.org` buffers, Agenda buffer, etc.). Before implementing your solution my init was only correcting the size of all `.org` buffers. Now I still have some buffers with small fonts (dried, message, etc.) but it's ok since I don't use them so often.

Comment: FYI I think I fixed the size of the org buffers with this: `  (custom-theme-set-faces
   'user
   '(variable-pitch ((t (:family "spectral" :height 180))))
   '(fixed-pitch ((t ( :family "Fira Code Retina" :height 0.8))))
   )`. Also I guess Spacemacs theme is playing a role.

Comment: Is my config really bad?

Comment: Perhaps not: it may be the theme's fault.

Comment: Now when I refresh the Agenda buffer, the font size increases +3. Is there a way to fix Agenda buffer font size?

Comment: It says: text-scale-mode-amount is a variable defined in ‘face-remap.el’.  Its value is 3
Local in buffer *Org Agenda*; global value is 0.

Comment: See the edited answer for a modified function that checks whether the adjustment has been done already.